# How to Convert Text in Non-structured Format to JSON Format

Tags: python, json, aws-lambda

**Content of a Sample Input Text**

```
{'key1':'value1','msg1':"content1"} //line 1
{'key2':'value2','msg2':"content2"} //line 2
{'key3':'value3','msg3':"content3"} //line 3
```

Also, pointing out some notable characteristics of the input text

- Lacks a proper delimiter, currently each object {...} takes a new line "\n"
- Contains single quotes, which can be an issue since JSON (the expected output) accepts only double quotes
- Does not have the opening and closing curly brackets required by JSON

**Expected Output JSON**

```
{
   {
      "key1":"value1",
      "msg1":"content1"
   },
   {
      "key2":"value2",
      "msg2":"content2"
   },
   {
      "key3":"value3",
      "msg3":"content3"
   }
}
```

What I have tried, but failed

- json.dumps(input_text), but it cannot identify "\n" as the "delimiter"
- Appending a comma at the end of each object {...}, but encountered the issue of extra comma when it comes to the last object

Comment: why aws lambda is related to the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have one dictionary per line, you can replace newlines with `,` and enclose the whole in brackets `[`,`]` (you get a list of dictionaries).
You can use `ast.literal_eval` to import your file as list of dictionaries.
Finally export it to json:

```
import json
import ast
with open("file.txt", "r") as f:
    dic_list = ast.literal_eval("[" + f.read().replace('\n',',') + "]")

print(json.dumps(dic_list, indent=4))
```

Output:

```
[
    {
        "key1": "value1",
        "msg1": "content1"
    },
    {
        "key2": "value2",
        "msg2": "content2"
    },
    {
        "key3": "value3",
        "msg3": "content3"
    }
]
```

Comment: `ast.literal_eval(",".join(f.read().splitlines()))`

Answer (score 1):

Just use `ast`

```
import ast
with open('test.txt') as f:
  data = [ast.literal_eval(l.strip()) for l in f.readlines()]
print(data)
```

output

```
[{'key1': 'value1', 'msg1': 'content1'}, {'key2': 'value2', 'msg2': 'content2'}, {'key3': 'value3', 'msg3': 'content3'}]
```

Comment: `[ast.literal_eval(l) for l in f]`